# Suppose $R$ and $S$ are symmetric relations on $A$. Prove that $R \circ S$ is symmetric iff $R \circ S = S \circ R$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R$ and $S$ are symmetric relations on $A$. Prove that $R \circ S$ is symmetric iff $R \circ S = S \circ R$

My attempt:

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose $R \circ S$ is symmetric.

We need to show that

1. $R \circ S \subseteq S \circ R$
2. $S \circ R \subseteq R \circ S$

1.

Suppose $(x,y) \in R \circ S$. Then $(y,x) \in R \circ S$

Since $(y,x) \in R \circ S$, we have some $a$ such that $(y,a) \in S$ and $(a,x) \in R$. Since $R,S$ are both symmetric we have $(a,y) \in S$ and $(x,a) \in R$, which implies that $(x,y) \in S \circ R$.

Arbitrary element was considered, hence $R \circ S \subseteq S \circ R$

2.

Suppose $(x,y) \in S \circ R$. There is some $a$ such that $(x,a) \in R$ and $ (a,y) \in S$. Since $R,S$ are symmetric, we conclude that $(a,x) \in R$ and $(y,a) \in S$. It implies that $(y,x) \in R \circ S$. And since $R \circ S$ is symmetric, we conlcude that $(x,y) \in R \circ S$. Arbitrary element was considered, hence $S \circ R \subseteq R \circ S$.

Both directions were shown, thus $R \circ S = S \circ R$.

$(\leftarrow)$

Suppose $R \circ S = S \circ R$

Consider arbitrary $(x,y) \in R \circ S$. Required to show that $(y,x) \in R \circ S$.

Since  $(x,y) \in R \circ S$, we have $(x,a) \in S$ and $(a,y) \in R$.

Since $R,S$ are symmetric, we conclude that $(a,x) \in S$ and $(y,a) \in R$, which implies that $(y,x) \in S \circ R$.

$R \circ S = S \circ R$, therefore $(y,x) \in R \circ S$.

Arbitrary element was considered.

Therefore, $R \circ S$ is symmetric.

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: That looks correct to me. I would just adapt some details. For example when you say *Since  $(x,y) \in R \circ S$, we have $(x,a) \in S$ and $(a,y) \in R$.*, I would say *Since  $(x,y) \in R \circ S$, **it exists $a \in A$** such that $(x,a) \in S$ and $(a,y) \in R$*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks okay to me.

Here is a shortcut based on the fact that a relation $T$ on $A$ is symmetric if and only if $T^{\text{op}}=T$.

---

We have $R^{\text{op}}=R$ and $S^{\text{op}}=S$.

Then: $$S\circ R=S^{\text{op}}\circ R^{\text{op}}=\left(R\circ S\right)^{\text{op}}$$

So that: $$\left(R\circ S\right)^{\text{op}}=R\circ S\iff S\circ R=R\circ S$$